# How to catch the result of an intent in Listview's CustomListAdapter class in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, arraylist, onactivityresult

I have an ArrayList which has objects of type Person. Person class has fields name, address1, address2, city, state, postcode and country. I want to be able to edit a particular person and  then update the changes such that the ListAdapter which displays the Persons shows updated data. This ListView is contained in RecipientActivity (Activity A)

In the custom Adapter I start the Activity RecipientAddressActivity (Activity B) using an intent in the TextView's onClick event:

```
holder.txtRecName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent rec_Intent = new Intent(context,
                                        RecipientAddressActivity.class);
            rec_Intent.putExtra("Current_Recipient",
                                         recipientArray.get(index));
            rec_Intent.putExtra("RecipientIndex",index);
            context.startActivity(rec_Intent);          

        }
    });
```

In the Activity B I get the Current_Recipient and the index in onCreate() event like this:

```
current_rec = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
            "Current_Recipient");
Recipient_Index = getIntent().getIntExtra("RecipientIndex", 151);
```

In the same activity, I have a button "Save" and on its Onclick I create a Person object which can be either a new Person or an old person being edited.

Button Save's onClick() event

```
{
  Intent Recipient_info = new Intent();
  Person recipient = new Person(edt_rec_name.getText().toString(),
   edt_rec_addr1.getText().toString(),edt_rec_addr2.getText().toString(),
   edt_rec_city.getText().toString(), edt_rec_state.getText().toString(),
   edt_rec_pcode.getText().toString(), edt_rec_country.getText().toString()); 
   Recipient_info.putExtra("Person", recipient);
   Recipient_info.putExtra("RecipientIndex", Recipient_Index);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, Recipient_info);
   finish();
}
```

The problem is there are 2 ways of starting Activity B. I don't know where or how to catch the result when Actvity B is started using ListView's Adapter.

Please help me asap. Kindly let me know if some more code or explanation is required.

Thanks.

Comment: does your Person class implement parcelable?

Comment: @Raghunandan No it implements Serializable.

Comment: for android parcelable is better than serializable. googe search for a example and follow the tutorials

Comment: @Raghunandan How does it solve the above problem?

Comment: i said it is better to use parcelable then serializable check the docs. Its a suggestion not a solution. Its upto you to follow or leave it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that in your code:

you are not starting activity as `activityForResult`.

check that and try now! if you still face this problem than here are some links, that will be useful in your problem:

[calling onActivityResult from CustomArray adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669636/calling-onactivityresult-from-customarray-adapter)

[onActivityResult in not called in the class extended from ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258722/onactivityresult-in-not-called-in-the-class-extended-from-arrayadapter)

[How to add item in Custom listView in onActivityResult method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907984/how-to-add-item-in-custom-listview-in-onactivityresult-method)

[How to Call onActivityResult in adapter listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576274/how-to-call-onactivityresult-in-adapter-listview)